# Is anyone indexing ArcGIS Server services on the web?

Tags: arcgis-server, rest

In looking at the REST API, it seems like it wouldn't be that hard to write a bot that crawls the web and indexes services (Map Services, GP Services etc.)

Is anyone already doing this?

**Update1:**
I can find lots of mapservices with simple [google search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=%22View+in%3A%22+%28MapServer%29&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=).

I rather doubt google gives a very high ranking to mapservice pages though, so I'd bet there are a lot that are missed.  Anyway, if someone were to crawl all these mapservice pages and assemble an index and expose that index on a site.  The site could allow me to search for  mapservices that are in a particular region and contain certain keywords and add the mapservices to my map.  AFAIK the [arcgis.com map gallery](http://www.arcgis.com/home/gallery.html) isn't built by a web crawler.

**Update2**
With a funcion named MapServiceHarvester, it sure sounds like Richie Carmichael [might be cooking something up](http://kiwigis.blogspot.com/2011/03/google-custom-search-in-c.html).

Comment: It's definitely crossed my mind, but no, I haven't actually done it.

Answer (score 4):

A more refined search: [inurl:arcgis/rest/services](http://www.google.com/search?q=inurl%3Aarcgis%2Frest%2Fservices)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want services you didn't know about. I think this one updates services you do know about.

[update service](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/net_server_doc/developer/scenarios/develop_ags_ws_client.htm)

Update:

Maybe you couldcome up with an algorythm to search for [rest](http://events.esri.com/uc/QandA/index.cfm?fuseaction=answer&conferenceId=85D7FF7F-1422-2413-199D382F1109DE0A&questionId=2255) services?

Spatial bridge says they will tell you how [here](http://www.spatialbridge.com/blog/25-gis-portals).

And finally maybe playing with [geoportal](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/geoportal/index.html) you could see some methodology and implement on a larger scale.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but yes, I'd like to find out about new mapservices.