# Is there a map of map services somewhere?

Tags: web-service

I'd like to provide a map based search of map services in a web app.

Ideally, I'd like a web service that displays markers at different zoom levels: local, municipal, county, regional, state or national level.  When I click on a marker, I'd like to see a list of urls representing the map services published by that governmental entity.

For example, for a typical state I would expect to see a marker for each county that has public web mapping services.  The marker would appear on the county seat, and would contain a url to that counties' map services.

My primary focus is Texas, USA, but any examples of map service map services would be useful.

Comment: I was going to jump in and say arcgis.com and the related ArcGIS.com on-premise product, but oddly enough... I don't see a map of maps... just a text based search.

Comment: I think it's time for someone to build this...which is what I said last time you brought up something similar ;) http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4985/is-anyone-indexing-arcgis-server-services-on-the-web

Comment: @derek - I've generalized my search for any sort of map - not just arcgis.  I'm also surprised there isn't something like this in google earth.

Answer (score 1):

**ONE Geology** does this (Europe centric)

Limited USA data - but you can add your own or public WMS links to the map

[image]

http://portal.onegeology.org/
(Internet Explorer 7,8,9 only)

More technical details here
http://www.onegeology.org/wmsCookbook/home.html

Answer (score 1):

Although not a map, a carefully crafted google search through the [API](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html) could work wonders:

[getcapabilities application/vnd.ogc.wms_xml site:.gov](http://www.google.co.uk/#q=getcapabilities+application/vnd.ogc.wms_xml+site%3a.gov+)

Comment: If you combined those URLs with  a Geoip database, you could make a map :)